# How to import Liferay theme?

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

I am trying to import a default Luminis Platform theme (LP5-ellucian-theme) which I copied from a Test server onto my local machines so I can do some theme development. I copied this theme folder into my PluginsSDK/themes/ directory, but when I go to File->New->Liferay Project from Existing Source and select this theme directory Eclipse tells me "Invalid project location".

What am I doing wrong here and/or is there another way to import this theme onto my local instance of Liferay?

Test server:

- Liferay Portal  6.1

My local machine:

- Liferay Portal 6.1
- Plugins SDK 6.1.2
- Liferay IDE 2.0
- Eclipse Kepler

[image: invalid project location]

[image: theme folder in SDK directory]

Answer (score 2):

Theme project has different folder structure in case of plugin-sdk and in tomcat/webapps when its deployed.
In plugin-sdk, you will find folder named as _diff which contains custom css,vm etc file which overrides parent theme.

I would suggest to create new theme in plugin-sdk, and just have modified css, vm files of your server theme copied under _diffs folder.

Comment: adding to this: Don't copy all of the files that you find in your theme into the _diffs folder: Detect which files are different from Liferay's _styled theme (which is used as basis by default) and only copy those files into the _diffs folder. If the theme has been written properly, it might only be a handful of files, easing maintenance a lot.